# clickable table cells - different dropdown lists based on cell content

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

Each of the cells in the table below, generated by php/mysql (cells generated by a `loop` through dates `foreach` employee. Each cell is clickable other than the headings.

When the user clicks on a cell I want a dropdown box to appear with a number of options which depending on whether the cell has a shift in it or not.

At the moment if I click an empty cell on **any** employees row it will open the dropdown in the **first** employee's **first** empty cell.

**How can I name or identify these drop down lists in a dynamic way so that the javascript function will open the correct dropdown for the correct cell?**

I know that use of an array/list would be most appropriate, but can't figure out how get js to identify it.

The complete code for the timetable at the bottom will put:

```
echo "<td onclick='myFunction()' class='dropbtn'>";
echo "<div class='dropdown'>";
echo "<div id='dropdown' class='dropdown-content'>";
echo "<a href='#'>Link 1</a>";
echo "<a href='#'>Link 2</a>";
echo "<a href='#'>Link 3</a>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</td>;
```

As each empty cell on an employee's row (not the unassigned ones).

Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("dropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Timetable]

PHP to generate timetable

```
$week = $_POST['week'];
$year = $_POST['y'];

for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){  
$gendates = new DateTime();
$gendates->setISODate($year,$week,1 + $i); 
$datesarray[$i] = $gendates->format('Y-m-d'); 
}

echo "<table class='editweektable'><tr>";
    echo "<th>Employee</th>";
        foreach($datesarray as $key => $date){
            echo "<th>".date("D", strtotime($date))."<br>".date("d-m", strtotime($date))."</th>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";

    $getunassigned->execute();
    while($row = $getunassigned->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        echo "<tr><td>Unassigned</td>";
            foreach($datesarray as $key => $date){
                echo "<td>";
                if($row['date'] == $date){
                    echo date("H:i", strtotime($row['starttime']))." - ".date("H:i", strtotime($row['finishtime']));
                } else { 
                    //empty cell 
                }
                echo "</td>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    $getemployees->execute();

    while($row1 = $getemployees->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        echo "<tr><td>".$row1['fname']." ".$row1['lname']."</td>";
            foreach($datesarray as $key => $date){
            echo "<td  onclick='myFunction()' class='dropbtn'>";
            $eid = $row1['eid'];
            $getemployeeshifts->execute();
            $row2 = $getemployeeshifts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $count = $getemployeeshifts->rowCount();
            if($count == 0){
                echo "<div class='dropdown'>";
                echo "<div id='myDropdown' class='dropdown-content'>";
                echo "<a href='#'>Link 1</a>";
                echo "<a href='#'>Link 2</a>";
                echo "<a href='#'>Link 3</a>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";

            } else {
                echo date("H:i", strtotime($row2['starttime']))." - ".date("H:i", strtotime($row2['finishtime']));
            }


            echo "</td>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";    
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Your JS  uses getElementById("dropdown") but you don't have an element with an id dropdown, it uses class instead

Comment: Edited example, see above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the id of the dynamically generated dropdowns to something related to the cell (date and employee)

```
echo "<div class='dropdown'>";
echo "<div id='MyDropdown".$eid.$date."' class='dropdown-content'>";
echo "<a href='#'>Link 1</a>";
echo "<a href='#'>Link 2</a>";
echo "<a href='#'>Link 3</a>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
```

And then javascript

```
function myFunction(eid, date) {
    document.getElementById("MyDropdown"+eid+date).classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Never duplicate the id of a element and to solve the reference of the DOM element you can pass this to the function :)

Update: added online example: https://jsfiddle.net/gdn5mfvo/

**Example table, dont duplicate id**

```
<table style="width:500px">
  <tr>
    <td onclick='myFunction(this)' class='dropbtn'>
        <div class='dropdown hide'>
            <div id='myDropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
                <a href='#'>Link 1</a>
                <a href='#'>Link 2</a>
                <a href='#'>Link 3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        click here
    </td>
    <td onclick='myFunction(this)' class='dropbtn'>
        <div class='dropdown hide'>
            <div id='myDropdown2' class='dropdown-content'>
                <a href='#'>Link 1</a>
                <a href='#'>Link 2</a>
                <a href='#'>Link 3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        click here
    </td>    
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Example JS**

```
<script>
    function myFunction(elem) {
        // elem points to the td clicked
        // elem.firstChild.nextSibling refernce to <div class='dropdown hide'> of the clicked td
        console.log(elem.firstChild.nextSibling.classList.toggle('hide'));
    }
</script>
```

**Example css**

```
<style>
    table, th, td {
       border: 1px solid black;
       height:10px;
    }
    .hide{
    display:none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, nothing happens when I click the td now. And I have ensured that id's are never reused

Comment: try it yourself, tis working. If your are having some problem with the example look at the console (F12), added online example https://jsfiddle.net/gdn5mfvo/